# View does not update when NgModel is updated Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

In my code I update the parent component home using an EventEmitter in the child component.

When the function this.getPrismClientLocatorExceptions() is called, the ngModel, this.tableData is updated but the table in the view does not update with the new data.  How do I get the view to update or for the childComponent to detect this change?

```js
import {
 Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientService } from '../../Services/clientService.service';
import { TableComponent } from '../table/table.component';

// ReSharper disable once TsResolvedFromInaccessibleModule
@Component({
 selector: 'home',
 templateUrl: './home.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
 providers: [ClientService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 columns: string[] = ['prismClientName', 'officeName', 'contr_Cmpy_NM', 'exceptionType', 'id'];
 @Input() tableData: PrismClientGrid[];

 constructor(public http: Http, private _router: Router, private _clientService: ClientService) {}
 ngOnInit() {
  this.getPrismClientLocatorExceptions();
 }
 getPrismClientLocatorExceptions() {
  return this._clientService.GetPrismClientLocatorExceptions().subscribe((data) => {
   this.tableData = data.json() as PrismClientGrid[];
  });
 }
 onDeleted(deleted: boolean) {
  this.getPrismClientLocatorExceptions();
 }
}
interface PrismClientGrid {
 prismClientName: string;
 officeName: string;
 exceptionType: string;
 contr_Cmpy_NM: string;
 contractorID: number;
 prismClientID: number;
}
```

```html
<script>
 $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
<h1>Client Exceptions By Office</h1>
<div *ngIf='tableData'>
 <table-component (deleted)="onDeleted($event)" [data]="tableData" [displayedColumns]="columns"></table-component>
</div>
```

```js
import {
 Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';
import { ClientService } from '../../Services/clientService.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'table-component',
 styleUrls: ['table.component.css'],
 templateUrl: 'table.component.html',
 providers:[ClientService]
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() data: any[];
 @Input() displayedColumns: string[];
 @Output() deleted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
 dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any[]>;

 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

 constructor(private _clientService: ClientService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
 }

 applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
   this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
  }
 }
 delete(exception: any) {
  let cle = {
   contractorID: exception.contractorID,
   officeName: exception.officeName,
   prismClientID: exception.prismClientID
  };
  this._clientService.DeleteClientLocatorException(cle).subscribe((data) => {
   this.deleted.emit(true);
   this.dataSource.disconnect();
   this.dataSource.connect();
  });;
 }
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
 <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort [trackBy]="id">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="prismClientName">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Prism Client Name </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.prismClientName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="officeName">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Office Name </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.officeName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="contr_Cmpy_NM">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Company Name </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.contr_Cmpy_NM}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="exceptionType">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Exception Type </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.exceptionType}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <a mat-raised-button (click)="delete(row)">REMOVE</a></td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
 </table>

 <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>


<!-- Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```

Comment: What I can think of is that you are assigning `tableData` only once on `ngOnInit`. Upon another call, there may be a new `tableData` but the `dataSource` points to the old object initialised on ngOnInit. Please give a try to `ngOnChanges` and initialise the `dataSource` once `tableData` changes. Let me know the result.

Comment: I would say try to use two-way data binding with your table component
Check this link: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AnkitSharma ngOnChanges worked for needing to update the table data.

Here is the ngOnChanges function I implemented to get the dataSource to reload and display the data correctly.

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(changes.data.currentValue);
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
 }
```

Also had to add an ngModel attribute to the table.component.html,

```html
<table mat-table (ngModel)="data" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort [trackBy]="id">
```

I also had to add OnChanges, SimpleChanges to be imported from @angular/core, then change the class to implement OnChanges.